# Is there any documentation on the 2008 version of System.Windows.Forms ( Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI )

Tags: .net, windows

I have the misfortune to have to maintain a application that makes extensive use of these DLLs, shown with their Build Date/Time :

```
  Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.WinForms.dll:
   4896A9C9 time date stamp Mon Aug  4 08:03:37 2008
  
  Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.dll:
   468A2943 time date stamp Tue Jul  3 11:47:31 2007

  Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.dll:
   468A2942 time date stamp Tue Jul  3 11:47:30 2007
```

Trying to build this application against the latest System.Windows.Forms DLLs produces about 10,000 error messages (it is large).

My problem is that none or very few of the classes defined in these DLLs conform to any extant documentation online.

For instance, the TreeNodeCollection class has no 'Item' property
so accessing nodes via Index is not possible - yet from .NET v1.0
onwards, the class is meant to provide an Item property, according
to all documentation I can find.

Any information anyone can provide as to what Standards or Specifications the contents of these DLLs conform to, or on where I might find documentation on their contents, or on how I might generate a list of all members of all classes in the DLL, with method signatures and type names, would be much appreciated.

Yes, we are planning to scrap use of C# altogether, and use of .NET / Windows GUI frameworks entirely, and use FLTK & C++ instead. This will be a long term project.

But meanwhile, we must maintain this application, used by a large number of our customers.

If anyone can suggest where I might find any documentation on
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.*, from 2007-2008, please let me know.

I have searched learn.microsoft.com & WayBack Machine copies of msdn.microsoft.com websites for hours without success. All docs I can find insist TreeNodeCollection must have an 'Item' Property, but in
the version we use it doesn't . Anyone have any ideas / pointers as to where I might find documentation for this ancient version of Microsoft.Practices.System.Windows.Forms ?

Comment: Look at the assembly version numbers, work out what .NET Framework version that is, and then go to the documentation. Note for software than is >12 years old you are very much into legacy. But these appear to not be .NET Framework, but from the very obsolete "Patterns & Practices" additions... which was always n unsupported set of extensions.

Comment: You can use reflection to enumerate the types and type members in an assembly.

Comment: @Richard - thanks! But where do I get the assembly version numbers?
I don't see them in 'dumpbin /all $DLL' output.
Sorry, I am a Windows Newbie.

Comment: And how could I go about 'using Reflection to enumerate the types and type members in an assembly' ?
Note we have ONLY the DLLs - nothing else .

Comment: Load the assembly which gives an `Assembly` reference. Then `Assembly.GetTypes()` (or `GetExportedTypes()`)

Comment: Aha! In VS2019, when I click on the 'Reference' for
Microsoft.Practices.CompositeUI.*, it says:
  Version :  1.0.51205.0
But that is just the Microsoft.Practices version, not the .NET version?
How do I "work out what .NET Framework that is" ?

Comment: OK, thanks , I'll try the Reflection route . At least then I'd know what
the actual contents are .

Comment: Look at the assembly's dependencies. (This is not the place for a tutorial on the basics of how .NET dependecnies work.)(

Comment: Hint, took one search to find https://github.com/mspnp

Comment: Documentation for that namespace is readily available.  It does not have an alternate version of TreeNodeCollection, "Item" is the common alias for [the indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.item?view=netframework-2.0) of a collection class.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for anyone else in this situation, I found 'ildasm.exe'
from:
${VS2019_INSTALL_DIR}\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools
(added to $PATH by vcvarsall.bat)
to be most useful in presenting a list of all exported symbols/types
from an Assembly DLL, including method signatures, Events, & Event
Source / Sinks .

Comment: Hope one day you find tools like ILSpy, way better to use.